# if a variable in my while loop is empty, echo a 0 instead of nothing

Tags: php, variables, string

I have the following loop:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    <some code>
     if ($user)
                echo '<li><a href="mahjong.php?layout='.$row['LayoutName'].'"><img src="images/layouts/'. $row['LayoutName'].'.png" alt="" /> <img src="images/'. $row['Stars'].'.png" alt="" /></a>
                        <div class="info">
                            <h2>'.$row['LayoutName'].'</h2>
                            <p>'.$row['LayoutTiles'].' Tiles, '.$row['LayoutLayers'].' Layers</p>
                            <hr size=2 color="white"> 
                            <p>Score: '.$row['Score'].'</p> 
                            <p>Time:&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row['Time'].'</p>
                        </div>
                      </li>';
            else 
    <some more code> 
}
```

This while loop works perfectly, but sometimes some variables have no data. This is correct, because there is simple none in the database. If this happens, it shows nothing. I want it so, that if the variable is empty, it echoes a 0.

Example `$row['Score']` = empty -> 0

Thanks,

ps it is possible that `$row['Time']` has a value and `$row['Score']` not!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
'<p>Score: '.(empty($row['Score'])?"0":$row['Score']).'</p> '
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

In recent PHP versions you can use `$row['Score'] ?: 0` etc.

Comment: aka coalesce. if null, use this other value instead.

Comment: should mention this is new to PHP 5.3 as far as I am aware.

Comment: Didn't realise you can do this. Good to know.

Comment: you would put the ?:0 right after the ending bracket... on $row['Score'] just like shown in his answe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leave the code as it is you could use the sql method coalesce:

```
select coalesce(score, 0) as score from table
```

coalesce returns the first non-null parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($row['score']==""){
 echo "0"; 
 }
```

Use this in your p tag after score

Answer (score -1):

I would create a helper function:

```
function valueOrZero($value) {
    if(!empty($value)) {
        return $value;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And use that in your view on each $row['variable'], e.g., `<p>Score: '.valueOrZero($row['Score']).'</p>`.

**Edit:** changed logic.

Comment: `isset()` only makes sense when accepting the variable as a reference. Otherwise passing an undefined variable will trigger a notice. Besides that, a variable that is set to NULL will already fail the `isset()` check.